# Partial Screen Refresh in Android

Tags: android, textview, imageview, refresh, partial

I have a Activity which has 2 components

1. Image view
2. Text view

Here the image in the image view is changed using a timer. This works fine. The text is scrolling text is marquee. Individually these works fine.

My problem is when the image gets changed it also reset the marquee string.

Is there any way to avoid this?

Is there any way to refresh the display partially in android.

Edit

```
File imgFolder = new File(config.AppDataDir+config.MainImagesDir); 
if(imgFolder.isDirectory()) { 
     File[] imageList = imgFolder.listFiles(); 
     if(imageList!=null) { 
         if(imageList.length>0) { 
            if(imageList[currentImageNum].exists()){ 
                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageList[currentImageNum++].getAbsolutePath()); 
                ImageHolder.setImageBitmap(myBitmap); 
            } 
            if(currentImageNum>=imageList.length) 
                currentImageNum =0; 
         } 
     }
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: please show us your code

Comment: File imgFolder = new  File(config.AppDataDir+config.MainImagesDir);
     if(imgFolder.isDirectory())
     {
      File[] imageList = imgFolder.listFiles();
      if(imageList!=null)
      {
       if(imageList.length>0)
       {
        
        if(imageList[currentImageNum].exists()){
   
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageList[currentImageNum++].getAbsolutePath());
            ImageHolder.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
            
        }
        if(currentImageNum>=imageList.length)
         currentImageNum =0;
         
       }
      }
     }

Comment: There is not any TextView related code so may be this not any affected with TextView marquee

Answer (score 0):

Normally, changing the source of an `ImageView` should not have any implications on other views. Most probably when changing the image you are doing something that is reflected on the `TextView` too.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
Here is my code for changing the images.
`File imgFolder = new  File(config.AppDataDir+config.MainImagesDir);
 if(imgFolder.isDirectory())
 {
     File[] imageList = imgFolder.listFiles();
     if(imageList!=null)
     {
      if(imageList.length>0)
      {
       if(imageList[currentImageNum].exists()){
          Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageList[currentImageNum++].getAbsolutePath());
          ImageHolder.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
      }
        if(currentImageNum>=imageList.length)
         currentImageNum =0;
         
       }
      }
     }`